# Laravel custom Authenication with different fields

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have a table in my database called (users_system) contains:

- user_id
- user_pass (plain text)

... some other fields

What I want is to be able to do laravel(5.2) authentication using those two fields considering the `(Auth::attempt)` only deal with email and hashed password.

So is that possible and if so how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check credentials and login user manually:

```
$userSystem = UserSystem::where('user_id', $userId)->where('user_pass', $password)->first();
if (!is_null($userSystem)) {
    // Manually login user.
    $user = User::find($userId);
    Auth::login($user);
}
```

But this is a terrible idea to use plain text passwords. You should never do that in a real app.

Comment: this gives the following error

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given

Comment: @BecauseGeek that is because you're using wrong ID or something. Make sure `$user = User::find($userId)` gets the user. For example, if `$userId = 5` and you do not have a user with this ID, it'll return `null`

Comment: you're right, i changed my table primary key in User model and it worked, but now i have another problem when i do Auth::logout(); which is:

Error Message : ORA-00904: "UPDATED_AT": invalid identifier
Position : 52
Statement : update ums.users_password set remember_token = :p0, updated_at = :p1 where user_sys_id = :p2

i guess that because i dont have updated at and remember me token so how to fix this

Comment: @BecauseGeek this error is not related to your question, so you should ask another question and post all related code there.